# angular-xeditable: Can we have multiple activationEvent to enable edit mode

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

angular-xeditable: Can we have multiple activationEvent to enable edit mode through events like focus and click. Both would enable edit mode.

xeditable.js:
    /**
    * Event, on which the edit mode gets activated. 
    * Can be any event.
    *
    * @var {string} activationEvent
    * @memberOf editable-options
    */
    activationEvent: 'click'

```
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/37/
```

On focus it just highlights the element do not enable edit mode. Edit opens up on click event (mouse left click or keyboard enter key)

Comment: can you share code snippet with us?

Comment: I don't have code snippet to share. I will create or share available jsfiddle code which have small table with few columns editable. I want those columns to change to edit mode when user clicks them or navigate to them via keyboard tabbing (focus).

Comment: Ok let us know when your fiddle is ready...